# Runtime library error connected with vector

Tags: c++

This is my code which task is to check how many times does the number appear in my array.
Error message tells me that vector subscript is out of range.

```
int main() {
    vector<int> numbers(1,-1);
    int x;
    int z;
    bool exit;

    int digits[] = { 2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 6, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 7, 9, 5, 9, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 7 };

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(digits) / sizeof(int)); i++) {
        z = 0;
        bool exit = 1;

        for (int j = 0; j < (sizeof(digits) / sizeof(int)); j++) {
            x = digits[i];
            for (int y = 0; y < (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int)); y++) {
                if (x == numbers[y]) {
                    bool exit = 0;
                }
            }

            if (digits[j] == x && exit) {
                z++;
            }
        }

        if (exit) {
            cout << "Liczba: " << x << " wystepuje: " << z << " razy" << endl;
            numbers.push_back(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Visual studio tells me that my code is valid but then during compilation , cmd shows me the error message which tells me that **Vector subscript out of range** . I just can't figure it out how to fix it exactly , bcs i have not found that i would initialize the vector which would not exist .

Comment: I agree with @LightnessRaceswithMonica - comment removed

Answer (score 2):

At least this statement

```
for (int y = 0; y < (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int)); y++) {
```

does not make sense because the expression `sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int)` does not yield the number of elements in the vector. Instead use

```
for (int y = 0; y < numbers.size(); y++) {
```

If I have correctly understood your task then instead of the container `std::vector` it is better to use either `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    int digits[] = 
    { 
        2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 
        9, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 
        2, 6, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 7, 9, 5, 
        9, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 7 
    };

    std::map<int, size_t> frequency;

    for ( const auto &item : digits )
    {
        ++frequency[item];
    }

    for ( const auto &p : frequency )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1: 4
2: 10
3: 10
4: 7
5: 7
6: 4
7: 5
9: 3
```

Comment: ok thanks it worked out but anyway still i got like multiplied answers i mean any time the loop meets another digit it is showing how many times it was repeated in array i mean the code is showing at the end : Liczba 7 wystepuje 5 razy Liczba 7 wystepuje 5 razy Liczba 7 wystepuje 5 razy (Liczba means the digit and wystepuje means appear on the whole here) i would like to get only the one line .

Comment: @Quasi31 You code does not make sense and can be written much simpler.